# LINQ query for friends feed: how to allow only my friends to see my post updates?

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, social-networking

I have an web application where I have a Diary, this Diary has many posts of many users. I have my account, and I have my Diary, but only my friends and followers can see my diary posts.

My question is, how can I allow only my friends and followers to see my Diary posts? How would be this query for this?

I believe only 3 tables would be inserted in this query:

My DiaryPosts table:

```
-------------------------
| ID | UserID | Content |
-------------------------
```

My Friends table:

```
--------------------------
| ID | UserID | FriendID |
--------------------------
```

My Followers table:

```
----------------------------
| ID | UserID | FollowerID |
----------------------------
```

How could I perform a query where I select a range of friends and allow only them to see my Diary posts?

Comment: Do you really want to select a list of people permitted to see your posts, or do you need to filter the posts a user sees to only those permitted by your rules?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be going about this backwards.  You don't need to select a range of people permitted to see your posts.  You need to filter the posts people can see to those permitted by rule, no?

If that is the case, then for any user looking for diary posts, return the post if either:

a) The UserID in DiaryPosts is the UserID in Friends where their ID is the FriendID, or
b) The UserID in DiaryPosts is the UserID in Followers where their ID is the FollowerID

(a) assumes that they are your friend, but not necessarily the reverse.  If you am their friend but not vice versa and you want them to see your posts, you would have to add additional logic.

Because you need rows where either the friend or follower condition apply, you are going to need Left joins.

I don't have time to test this, so the syntax may be a bit rough, but I think you can start with something like this:

```
var x = from D in DiaryPosts
        from Fr in Friends 
        where (w => w.UserID = D.UserID)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
        from Fo in Followers  
        where (w => w.UserID == D.UserID)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
        where Fr.FriendID = myID | Fo.FriendID = myID
        select {D};
```

This should return all posts where you are a friend or a follower of the poster.  If you do actually just want a list of friend and follower IDs that can see your posts, let me know and I'll try to post that.

Comment: I couldn't get it, I'm trying to perform the request with all my needs but I can't do it. Any other sample?

Answer (score 0):

List of your friends and followers person Ids:

```
var Result = Friends.Where(p=>p.UserID==YourId).Select(p=>p.FriendID)
.Concat(Followers.Where(p=>p.UserID==YourId).Select(p=>p.FollowerID))
```